# VM Aborting :Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00001247 (code=-6)

Tags: android

I am using eclipse lollipop version.

I am getting this error :

> VM Aborting
>
> Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00001247 (code=-6)

Below I have posted the full stacktrace:

**StackTrace:**

```
01-30 04:11:43.053: E/dalvikvm(4679): VM aborting

01-30 04:11:43.053: A/libc(4679): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00001247 (code=-6), thread 4679 (e.quranmadeeasy)

01-30 04:11:43.541: D/dalvikvm(4749): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 124K, 6% free 3345K/3528K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
01-30 04:11:43.541: I/dalvikvm-heap(4749): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.395MB for 1127532-byte allocation
01-30 04:11:43.541: D/dalvikvm(4749): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 4% free 4446K/4632K, paused 1ms, total 1ms
```

Logcat didn't pointed out the error line.So I didn't know how to solve this error.I tried this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21595778/android-app-crashes-with-sigabrt-signal-6-only-while-eclipse-debugging).But It doesn't helpful to me.Any help is mostly appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: if it's crashing in libc then check you aren't trying to free() a null pointer in native code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Texview contents exceeds the gridview table size and throws fatal exception.I reduce the textview contents in Database and solved this error.

Comment: With an answer like this only you can understand what's happening. I am experiencing exactly the same error but it is really random and crashes on different test cases. So could you please answer in a more detailed way what was issue?

Comment: @karate For me I had more textview contents in one cell.So it exceeds the size of the particular content.After removed more contents fixed the issue

Answer (score 2):

Are you app use native method ? Can you get the DEBUG stack ? It will output on logcat, or you can found it on /data/tombstones. If you found, you can get information like this

```
backtrace:
#00  pc 0000d1a0  /system/lib/libc.so (write+12)
#01  pc 0001aac1  /system/lib/libc.so (__sflush+48)
#02  pc 0001bad7  /system/lib/libc.so (_fwalk+30)
#03  pc 0001f0d9  /system/lib/libc.so (__cxa_finalize+132)
#04  pc 0001f40b  /system/lib/libc.so (exit+6)
#05  pc 00016f9d  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+40)
#06  pc 000040a4  /system/bin/toolbox
```

Then you can found the problem, use addr2line get position on code. More info about addr2line in here : [How to use addr2line in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314036/how-to-use-addr2line-in-android)