# TeamViewer SDK - Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, libraries, teamviewer

recently I have tried importing **TeamViewer SDK** for Android to **Xamarin.Android**. I resolved binding and started my app and when I wanted to create a session according to their example it showed the TeamViewer icon and text "waiting for your partner to join session" or something like that, but after a **split of a second** it crashed with

> Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 23959 (pool-1-thread-1)

Everything runs fine on Android. Only Xamarin.Android has problems.

Does anybody have an idea what may be causing it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android app crashes with SIGABRT Signal 6 only while Eclipse debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21595778/android-app-crashes-with-sigabrt-signal-6-only-while-eclipse-debugging)

Answer (score 0):

add this line "System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable ("LANG", "C");" in the OnCreate method of the activity. This works for me.