# Cannot Debug using Galaxy s3 phone

Tags: java, android, eclipse, samsung-mobile

I have a project which is debugging perfectly on tablet and other devices, but when i attach galaxy s3 phone with my notebook, debugger dialog shows on the start of my activity but right after application crashes.

**here is the log cat:**

```
05-13 18:57:10.240: E/USB(12384): [CSSVC    ][Connsvc_USB_HandleOpen:2178   ] open /dev/android_ssusbcon failed (errno 2 : No such file or directory)
05-13 18:57:10.240: E/USB(12384): [CSSVC    ][Connsvc_USB_DeviceCreate:1259 ] Connsvc_USB_HandleOpen fail.
05-13 18:57:10.240: E/USB(12384): [CSSVC    ][Connsvc_USB_DeviceCreate:1316 ] -- Status -1
05-13 18:57:10.240: E/USB(12384): [CSSVC    ][Connsvc_USB_EnumDevice:211    ] Connsvc_USB_DeviceCreate fail, deviceName : /dev/android_ssusbcon
05-13 18:57:10.240: E/General(12384): [CSSVC    ][Connsvc_USB_Init:53   ]  -- Status : 0xfffffff4
05-13 18:57:10.240: E/General(12384): [CSSVC    ][Connsvc_Startup:84    ] Connsvc_USB_Init fail. status : -12
05-13 18:57:10.240: E/General(12384): [CSSVC    ][main:117  ] Connsvc_Startup fail. Status : -12


05-13 19:04:58.155: E/dalvikvm(13098): HEY: invalid 'this' ptr 0x1 (Lcom/samsung/android/multiwindow/MultiWindowApplicationInfos;.isSupportScaleApp (Landroid/content/pm/ActivityInfo;)Z)
05-13 19:04:58.155: E/dalvikvm(13098): VM aborting
05-13 19:04:58.155: A/libc(13098): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x0000332a (code=-6), thread 13098 (inderconference)
```

any one guide me what could be the issue?

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21595778/android-app-crashes-with-sigabrt-signal-6-only-while-eclipse-debugging) and its accepted answer could be of some help ?

Comment: @2Dee - what makes you think that has any relevance to this?

Comment: Does your app have a lot of pictures? And, can you show more of the logcat output?

Comment: Have you found the solution ? I am experiencing the same thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating i got to know, that in some of asian countries people are selling custom rom installed handsets, with some OS related modifications so it was custom android OS installed and that's why i had no permission to debug it.

otherwise, galaxy S3 has no issue in debugging if actual rom is installed.