# A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 5246 from web view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I'm working on an android application that uses recycler view in left swipe menu. The application runs fine on Samsung Note 3, Sony Xperia, Nexus 4 Android 5.1.1 but crashes when run on Note 4, S5, S6 etc. When i debugged, i found recyclerview is the main cause of the app crash and i get this in the logcat:

```
02-10 01:41:18.376 5246-5246/com.myapppackage E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
02-10 01:41:19.968 5246-5246/com.myapppackage A/chromium: [FATAL:jni_android.cc(269)] Check failed: false. Please include Java exception stack in crash report
--------- beginning of crash
02-10 01:41:19.968 5246-5246/com.myapppackage A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 5246 (stark.sponsored)
```

I have googled this error, went through stackoverflow but couldn't find anything good (not for my case). Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you forget to add APP_KEY to your app!  you look it

Answer (score 0):

the line:

```
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

**has no matter in this case** the problem is with web view

```
A/chromium: [FATAL:jni_android.cc(269)] Check failed: false.
```

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/base/+/master/android/jni_android.cc#269

what i can propose without more  info or debugging :

- check if u have installed webview in apps on NOTE 4
- if yes -> uninstall it and try launch
- if not -> install and try launch

if you'll be still encountered this fatal signal:

- try check your code for NullPointerExceptions specialy getView() getActivity() etc ....
- or if u not instantiating by mistake more of Web View class objects
- check if you're unloading web view on activity / fragment close for example in onDestroy() or onStop() methods

ps.

web view is very faulty/buggy when using on other devices as NEXUS :) 
google is not worrying on users who are using other "ports/distros" of AOSP OS like CM, AOKP etc  or devices with other kernels - thus those memory violation errors

ps2. you can look at comments to answer to this:

[Android app crashes with SIGABRT Signal 6 only while Eclipse debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21595778/android-app-crashes-with-sigabrt-signal-6-only-while-eclipse-debugging)