# When debugging android (Nexus 10, kitkat API 19) in Xamarin forms I get this error: Unfortunately, *Projectname* has stopped

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Been experimenting in my Android Build with "Used shared mono runtime" by having it enabled and disabled. I get the same error (Unfortunately, 'Projectnam' has stopped) by either one of them.

I am kinda lost right now not sure what to do. Could the virtual device (in this case, nexus 10) be the problem?

Giving you an image how my build looks right now, Use shared mono runtime disabled but I have tried to have it enabled as well without any difference.

[image]

Comment: you need to look at the application output / device logs - "project has stopped" is the generic Android message for "your code crashed"

Comment: okok. yeah there is a whole bunch of messages in the log when i start to debug the device. Should I post it here on the post so u might be able to see what it is? I cannot tell what it could be

Comment: Dont know how to post alot of code in stackoverflow so i put it up on a pastebin if u have the time to check it out: http://pastebin.com/X3WKAzsK

Comment: Tried to debug it with a androidphone now as well with the same outcome

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21595778/android-app-crashes-with-sigabrt-signal-6-only-while-eclipse-debugging which seems to be regarding the same problem. Probably, there is something wrong in your code, which causes the UI-Thread to hang. In that case Android may just kill your App with that error message at the end of your log (Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT)) posting some code may help give people an idea of what goes wrong, if you still cannot figure it out. I do not believe its connected to the shared runtime setting, though.

Comment: Solved it. Xamarin didnt like that I used a "." in my namespace