# Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00002b2b (code=-6), thread 11051

Tags: android, custom-keyboard

I Have Implemented **CustomKeyboard which extends KeyboardView** in my application. In Activity i have implemented **OnKeyboardActionListener** when user preses the keyboard keys onPress is called .. on continous key presses the onPress is called and i am updating the Edit Text(Edit Text Max Length is 140) after continous clicks in keyboard app crashes.

App Crashes and giving this LOG

```
09-30 12:21:44.977: A/libc(11051): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00002b2b (code=-6), thread 11051 (ui.cadillac.HMI)
```

I have checked previous Question in SO but I am not able fix

[What is fatal signal 6 in android logcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36693887/what-is-fatal-signal-6-in-android-logcat][1])

Pl Help