# Assertion at ../metadata.c:1043, condition `index < meta->heap_strings.size' not met

Tags: android, xamarin, mono

Im getting this strange error when i try to run an Xamarin.Android application. The app builds normally but on debugging i get this error:

```
04-02 17:50:55.902 W/monodroid-gc( 5812): GREF GC Threshold: 46080
04-02 17:50:56.132 F/ ( 5812): * Assertion at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-6/xamarin-android/external/mono/mono/metadata/metadata.c:1043, condition `index < meta->heap_strings.size' not met
04-02 17:50:56.142 F/libc ( 5812): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x000016b4 (code=-6), thread 5812 (t.appname)
```

Happened after i installed **Xamarin.Android.Support.Design** and set compile android version to 8.1

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yBiHeh4Q2aeKNYptQGc_qVx5bVZ0W3ON) is the project without the bin, obj and packages folders

Tried With VS 15.6.5 and still having the same issue. all NuGet packages are up to date

**EDIT2:** i have change the compile version from 8.1 to 8 and now i don't get this error. but why im, getting it on 8.1?

Comment: Can you provide a demo on github or onedrive? Or you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36693887/what-is-fatal-signal-6-in-android-logcat)

Comment: @JoeLv-MSFT i have update my question with the whole project