# App crashes on starting after closing it by calling finish() on activity

Tags: android, pjsip, pjsua2

I am working on an app based on PJSUA2. App works fine except when I close the app and try to restart it, It crashes with the below message:

```
12:23:32.847 evsub0x95b1d21  ........Subscription state changed NULL --> SENT
12:23:32.848   pjsua_pres.c  .........Presence subscription to sip:2003@10.13.30.27:5060 is SENT
```

11-22 12:23:32.849 20041-20041/com.aa.aaaaA/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 20041 (bbell.aaaa), pid 20041 (bbell.aaaa)
11-22 12:23:32.860 20041-20144/com.aa.aaaaI/System.out: 12:23:32.851   pjsua_core.c !.RX 495 bytes Response msg 404/SUBSCRIBE/cseq=1727 (rdata0x94f3f014) from UDP 10.13.30.27:5060:
    SIP/2.0 404 Not Found

I am unable to figure out the root cause nor the solution. Need your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We are unable to provide any solution without any code . Post the code block which causing error (Debug your code ). Meanwhile you can look into [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36693887/what-is-fatal-signal-6-in-android-logcat).

Answer (score 0):

i think you should make a check on  Subscription state on very firstActivity which launch after restarting app it may be Splash screen or anything you figure it out and try