# Add Flutter View/Fragment inside ViewPager in Android project crash

Tags: android, view, android-viewpager, flutter, fragment

When I try to add Flutter View/Fragment into ViewPager, I get this error:

> 2018-12-04 12:59:15.241 27893-27893/com.carnegie.opa.debug E/flutter:
>   [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm.cc(259)] VM snapshot must be valid.
>   2018-12-04 12:59:15.241 27893-27893/*.opa.debug A/flutter:
>   [FATAL:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(212)] Check failed: vm. Must be
>   able to initialize the VM.
>
> --------- beginning of crash 2018-12-04 12:59:15.242 27893-27893/*.opa.debug A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in
>   tid 27893 (negie.opa.debug) 2018-12-04 12:59:15.285 27991-27991/?
>   E/propClient: PropClient failed to load 2018-12-04 12:59:15.316
>   27992-27992/? A/DEBUG:*            
>      * 2018-12-04 12:59:15.317 27992-27992/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint:
>   'samsung/c7proltezh/c7proltechn:8.0.0/R16NW/C7010ZHU1CRG8:user/release-keys'
>   2018-12-04 12:59:15.317 27992-27992/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '4'
>   2018-12-04 12:59:15.317 27992-27992/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm' 2018-12-04
>   12:59:15.317 27992-27992/? A/DEBUG: pid: 27893, tid: 27893, name:
>   negie.opa.debug  >>> com.carnegie.opa.debug <<< 2018-12-04
>   12:59:15.317 27992-27992/? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6
>   (SI_TKILL), fault addr -------- 2018-12-04 12:59:15.321 27992-27992/?
>   A/DEBUG: Abort message: '[FATAL:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(212)]
>   Check failed: vm. Must be able to initialize the VM.
>       ' 2018-12-04 12:59:15.321 27992-27992/? A/DEBUG:     r0 00000000  r1 00006cf5  r2 00000006  r3 00000008 2018-12-04 12:59:15.322
>   27992-27992/? A/DEBUG:     r4 00006cf5  r5 00006cf5  r6 fff6d740  r7
>   0000010c 2018-12-04 12:59:15.322 27992-27992/? A/DEBUG:     r8
>   00000000  r9 fff6db04  sl d203ba00  fp fff6de48 2018-12-04
>   12:59:15.322 27992-27992/? A/DEBUG:     ip 00000000  sp fff6d730  lr
>   f0231737  pc f026295c  cpsr 200f0010 2018-12-04 12:59:15.339
>   27992-27992/? A/DEBUG: backtrace: 2018-12-04 12:59:15.339
>   27992-27992/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 0004b95c  /system/lib/libc.so
>   (tgkill+12) 2018-12-04 12:59:15.339 27992-27992/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc
>   0001a733  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+54) 2018-12-04 12:59:15.339
>   27992-27992/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 0053ea03 
>   /data/app/com.carnegie.opa.debug-y3wzGzzgqQuxa5lBgZbKLA==/lib/arm/libflutter.so
>   (offset 0x4e5000) 2018-12-04 12:59:15.339 27992-27992/? A/DEBUG:
>
> ## 03 pc 00536ba3  /data/app/com.carnegie.opa.debug-y3wzGzzgqQuxa5lBgZbKLA==/lib/arm/libflutter.so
>
> (offset 0x4e5000) 2018-12-04 12:59:15.339 27992-27992/? A/DEBUG:
>
> ## 04 pc 003e0f29  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+40) 2018-12-04 12:59:15.339
>
> 27992-27992/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 003dd1e1  /system/lib/libart.so
>   (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+64)

I have to mention that adding view/fragment to Activity or Fragment inside that activity works flawless. Only problem is adding Flutter content into ViewPager.

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you sure that this is the proper logcat? Because i can't see related error.

Comment: The only thing i can see is  `Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6`. See [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36693887/what-is-fatal-signal-6-in-android-logcat).

Comment: That is the only crash I get :) And it only happens when I try to instantiate and add Flutter fragment/view inside ViewPager.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25185

you must do these commands before you run the main project every time:

`$ cd .android/`

`$ ./gradlew app:assembleDebug`