# signal 6 (SIGABRT)

Tags: java, android

Have been struggling with this crash for days. Everything works fine when I try to load 1 single API Request at a time. However when I try to make simultaneous calls to my API the app crashes with no information clear information.

The requests are being send from an AsyncTask which first encrypts them via libsodium, and then posted them as a HttpURLConnection request.

The tombstone is attached here, is anyone able to clarify where the issue might be being caused?

Thanks

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86/generic_x86:9/PSR1.180720.012/4923214:userdebug/dev-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'x86'
pid: 15081, tid: 15372, name: AsyncTask #7  >>> id.starchand <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'java_vm_ext.cc:542] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: thread Thread[18,tid=15372,Native,Thread*=0xe1d17a00,peer=0x12dabd50,"AsyncTask #7"] using JNIEnv* from thread Thread[27,tid=15370,Native,Thread*=0xcb85c600,peer=0x12dabb68,"AsyncTask #6"]'
    eax 00000000  ebx 00003ae9  ecx 00003c0c  edx 00000006
    edi 00003ae9  esi 00000236
    ebp 00003211  esp 9a2622f8  eip ec87db59

backtrace:
    #00 pc 00000b59  [vdso:ec87d000] (__kernel_vsyscall+9)
    #01 pc 0001fdf8  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+40)
    #02 pc 00022ed3  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+115)
    #03 pc 004dc8a6  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+1174)
    #04 pc 005cd833  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIPFvPKcENS_9allocatorIS5_EES4_EclEOS3_+35)
    #05 pc 00007ccc  /system/lib/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+828)
    #06 pc 0031ab5f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+1775)
    #07 pc 0031ad21  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbortV(char const*, char const*, char*)+113)
    #08 pc 000d60f7  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::ScopedCheck::AbortF(char const*, ...)+71)
    #09 pc 000d46fc  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::ScopedCheck::CheckPossibleHeapValue(art::ScopedObjectAccess&, char, art::(anonymous namespace)::JniValueType)+364)
    #10 pc 000d3bdb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::ScopedCheck::Check(art::ScopedObjectAccess&, bool, char const*, art::(anonymous namespace)::JniValueType*)+811)
    #11 pc 000d7876  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::CheckJNI::DeleteRef(char const*, _JNIEnv*, _jobject*, art::IndirectRefKind)+918)
    #12 pc 000c038b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::CheckJNI::DeleteLocalRef(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+43)
    #13 pc 000014dd  /data/app/id.starchand-C3sToe1m35tQitoWEw7Q5A==/lib/x86/libed25519_android.so (SHA512_Update+173)
    #14 pc 0000162a  /data/app/id.starchand-C3sToe1m35tQitoWEw7Q5A==/lib/x86/libed25519_android.so (SHA512+58)
    #15 pc 000016a1  /data/app/id.starchand-C3sToe1m35tQitoWEw7Q5A==/lib/x86/libed25519_android.so (crypto_sign_keypair+81)
    #16 pc 00001001  /data/app/id.starchand-C3sToe1m35tQitoWEw7Q5A==/lib/x86/libed25519_android.so (Java_com_github_dazoe_android_Ed25519_ExpandPrivateKeyN+145)
    #17 pc 005f6b97  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+71)
    #18 pc 005f0d52  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+418)
    #19 pc 000a30df  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+239)
    #20 pc 0029bca2  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+338)
    #21 pc 00293e48  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1048)
    #22 pc 005bdc5f  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+207)
    #23 pc 005e2ea1  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14625)
    #24 pc 0004b594  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes33.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/id.starchand-C3sToe1m35tQitoWEw7Q5A==/base.apk!classes33.dex (deleted) (com.github.dazoe.android.Ed25519.ExpandPrivateKey+64)
    #25 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
    #26 pc 0026c79c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
    #27 pc 00293e2b  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
    #28 pc 005bdc5f  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+207)
    #29 pc 005e2ea1  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14625)
    #30 pc 0004b5ee  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes33.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/id.starchand-C3sToe1m35tQitoWEw7Q5A==/base.apk!classes33.dex (deleted) (com.github.dazoe.android.Ed25519.PublicKeyFromPrivateKey+62)
    #31 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
    #32 pc 0026c79c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
    #33 pc 00293e2b  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
    #34 pc 005bdc5f  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+207)
    #35 pc 005e2ea1  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14625)
    #36 pc 00062a80  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes33.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/id.starchand-C3sToe1m35tQitoWEw7Q5A==/base.apk!classes33.dex (deleted) (id.starchand.utils.SqrlLogin$CreateSignature.doInBackground+292)
    #37 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
    #38 pc 0026c79c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
    #39 pc 00293e2b  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
    #40 pc 005bc493  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+691)
    #41 pc 005e2d21  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14241)
    #42 pc 00062940  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes33.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/id.starchand-C3sToe1m35tQitoWEw7Q5A==/base.apk!classes33.dex (deleted) (id.starchand.utils.SqrlLogin$CreateSignature.doInBackground+4)
    #43 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
    #44 pc 0026c79c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
    #45 pc 00293e2b  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
    #46 pc 005bc493  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+691)
    #47 pc 005e2d21  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14241)
    #48 pc 00ad5a56  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.os.AsyncTask$2.call+40)
    #49 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
    #50 pc 0026c79c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
    #51 pc 00293e2b  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
    #52 pc 005bd574  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1444)
    #53 pc 005e2f21  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14753)
    #54 pc 0011312e  /system/framework/boot.vdex (java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run+62)
    #55 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
    #56 pc 0026c79c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
    #57 pc 00293e2b  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
    #58 pc 005bd574  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1444)
    #59 pc 005e2f21  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14753)
    #60 pc 00117114  /system/framework/boot.vdex (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker+162)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is fatal signal 6 in android logcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36693887/what-is-fatal-signal-6-in-android-logcat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check in which method you're calling HttpURLConnection, should be on doInBackground();
2. Try not to use AsyncTask, better use simple threads.
3. Even better way then previous one is to use Retrofit library for api requests. It has all needed functionality.