# Strange Android Exception

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Im developing an Android application and now I am getting a very strange error I have no idea why it happens. This is not my first app I am developing, but I never had such a error before. Maybe someone has an idea, what are possible causes of this. I also found no similar problem in the internet.

My project is also really big and so with this error message I dont really know which code could cause this, that is why here is no code.

```
A/zygote64: concurrent_copying.cc:2510] Check failed: it->AsMirrorPtr()->AtomicSetMarkBit(1, 0) 
A/zygote64: runtime.cc:492] Runtime aborting...
A/zygote64: runtime.cc:492] Aborting thread:
A/zygote64: runtime.cc:492] "HeapTaskDaemon" prio=5 tid=8 WaitingPerformingGc
A/zygote64: runtime.cc:492]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x1bb04b58 self=0x722bcd2a00
A/zygote64: runtime.cc:492]   | sysTid=29600 nice=4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7236c7d4f0
A/zygote64: runtime.cc:492]   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=3 stm=2 core=3 HZ=100
A/zygote64: runtime.cc:492]   | stack=0x7236b7b000-0x7236b7d000 stackSize=1037KB
"]   | held mutexes= "abort lock"
"]   native: #00 pc 000000000039770c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+212)
"]   native: #01 pc 000000000045dd74  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMapb+348)
"]   native: #02 pc 000000000044546c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState10DumpThreadERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEPNS_6ThreadE+56)
"]   native: #03 pc 000000000044527c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+456)
"]   native: #04 pc 00000000004372ec  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEPKc+172)
"]   native: #05 pc 0000000000437b60  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime7AborterEPKc+24)
"]   native: #06 pc 000000000052203c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN7android4base10LogMessageD1Ev+900)
"]   native: #07 pc 00000000001d3f34  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector17ConcurrentCopying11FinishPhaseEv+564)
"]   native: #08 pc 00000000001d2854  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector17ConcurrentCopying9RunPhasesEv+1552)
"]   native: #09 pc 00000000001e6688  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector16GarbageCollector3RunENS0_7GcCauseEb+352)
"]   native: #10 pc 000000000020a8a4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc4Heap22CollectGarbageInternalENS0_9collector6GcTypeENS0_7GcCauseEb+3632)
"]   native: #11 pc 0000000000218778  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc4Heap12ConcurrentGCEPNS_6ThreadENS0_7GcCauseEb+128)
"]   native: #12 pc 0000000000220aa8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc4Heap16ConcurrentGCTask3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+40)
"]   native: #13 pc 000000000024162c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc13TaskProcessor11RunAllTasksEPNS_6ThreadE+64)
"]   native: #14 pc 000000000020c8ac  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (???)
"]   at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.runHeapTasks(Native method)
"]   at java.lang.Daemons$HeapTaskDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:461)
"]   at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:103)
"]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
"] Dumping all threads without appropriate locks held: thread list lock mutator lock
"] All threads:
"] DALVIK THREADS (17):
"] "HeapTaskDaemon" prio=5 tid=8 Runnable
"]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x1bb04b58 self=0x722bcd2a00
"]   | sysTid=29600 nice=4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7236c7d4f0
"]   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=5 stm=2 core=3 HZ=100
"]   | stack=0x7236b7b000-0x7236b7d000 stackSize=1037KB
"]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
"]   native: #00 pc 000000000039770c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+212)
"]   native: #01 pc 000000000045dd74  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMapb+348)
"]   native: #02 pc 0000000000474d58  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art14DumpCheckpoint3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+880)
"]   native: #03 pc 000000000046d804  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList13RunCheckpointEPNS_7ClosureES2_+476)
"]   native: #04 pc 000000000046d214  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEb+796)
"]   native: #05 pc 000000000044528c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+472)
"]   native: #06 pc 00000000004372ec  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEPKc+172)
"]   native: #07 pc 0000000000437b60  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime7AborterEPKc+24)
"]   native: #08 pc 000000000052203c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN7android4base10LogMessageD1Ev+900)
"]   native: #09 pc 00000000001d3f34  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector17ConcurrentCopying11FinishPhaseEv+564)
"]   native: #10 pc 00000000001d2854  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector17ConcurrentCopying9RunPhasesEv+1552)
"]   native: #11 pc 00000000001e6688  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector16GarbageCollector3RunENS0_7GcCauseEb+352)
"]   native: #12 pc 000000000020a8a4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc4Heap22CollectGarbageInternalENS0_9collector6GcTypeENS0_7GcCauseEb+3632)
"]   native: #13 pc 0000000000218778  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc4Heap12ConcurrentGCEPNS_6ThreadENS0_7GcCauseEb+128)
"]   native: #14 pc 0000000000220aa8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc4Heap16ConcurrentGCTask3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+40)
"]   native: #15 pc 000000000024162c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc13TaskProcessor11RunAllTasksEPNS_6ThreadE+64)
"]   native: #16 pc 000000000020c8ac  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (Java_dalvik_system_VMRuntime_runHeapTasks__+124)
"]   at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.runHeapTasks(Native method)
"]   at java.lang.Daemons$HeapTaskDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:461)
"]   at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:103)
"]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
"] 
"] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
"]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x73514e10 self=0x72420c7a00
"]   | sysTid=29589 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7246d339b0
"]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=520 stm=49 core=2 HZ=100
"]   | stack=0x7fcd99e000-0x7fcd9a0000 stackSize=8MB
"]   | held mutexes=
"]   kernel: __switch_to+0x8c/0xe0
"]   kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xd0/0x160
"]   kernel: futex_wait+0xe4/0x210
"]   kernel: do_futex+0x168/0xc48
"]   kernel: SyS_futex+0x11c/0x1b0
"]   kernel: __sys_trace_return+0x0/0x4
"]   native: #00 pc 000000000001dc6c  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
"]   native: #01 pc 00000000000e1c5c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable16WaitHoldingLocksEPNS_6ThreadE+152)
"]   native: #02 pc 00000000004e18e8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3artL12GoToRunnableEPNS_6ThreadE+440)
"]   native: #03 pc 00000000004e16e8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art12JniMethodEndEjPNS_6ThreadE+28)
"]   native: #04 pc 00000000001faf7c  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce__JI+156)
"]   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native method)
"]   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
"]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
"]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6710)
"]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
"]   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
"]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
"] 
"] "Jit thread pool worker thread 0" prio=5 tid=2 Native
"]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x1bb00000 self=0x723720e000
"]   | sysTid=29594 nice=9 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x723780c4f0
"]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=189 stm=50 core=2 HZ=100
"]   | stack=0x723770e000-0x7237710000 stackSize=1021KB
"]   | held mutexes=
"]   kernel: __switch_to+0x8c/0xe0
"]   kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xd0/0x160
"]   kernel: futex_wait+0xe4/0x210
"]   kernel: do_futex+0x168/0xc48
"]   kernel: SyS_futex+0x11c/0x1b0
"]   kernel: __sys_trace_return+0x0/0x4
"]   native: #00 pc 000000000001dc6c  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
"]   native: #01 pc 00000000000e1c5c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable16WaitHoldingLocksEPNS_6ThreadE+152)
"]   native: #02 pc 000000000016f2fc  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art19HInstructionBuilder13ResolveMethodEtNS_10InvokeTypeE+476)
"]   native: #03 pc 000000000016fd2c  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art19HInstructionBuilder11BuildInvokeERKNS_11InstructionEjjjbPjj+380)
"]   native: #04 pc 000000000016ac04  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art19HInstructionBuilder21ProcessDexInstructionERKNS_11InstructionEj+940)
"]   native: #05 pc 0000000000169f24  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art19HInstructionBuilder5BuildEv+984)
"]   native: #06 pc 000000000013be50  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art13HGraphBuilder10BuildGraphEv+132)
"]   native: #07 pc 00000000001ad94c  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZNK3art18OptimizingCompiler10TryCompileEPNS_14ArenaAllocatorEPNS_19CodeVectorAllocatorEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEjNS_10InvokeTypeEtjNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEERKS5_NSA_INSB_8DexCacheEEEPNS_9ArtMethodEbPNS_24VariableSizedHandleScopeE+2520)
"]   native: #08 pc 00000000001af414  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art18OptimizingCompiler10JitCompileEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_3jit12JitCodeCacheEPNS_9ArtMethodEb+960)
"]   native: #09 pc 000000000012844c  /system/lib64/libart-compiler.so (_ZN3art3jit11JitCompiler13CompileMethodEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEb+160)
"]   native: #10 pc 00000000002f43bc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art3jit3Jit13CompileMethodEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadEb+472)
"]   native: #11 pc 00000000002f69ec  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art3jit14JitCompileTask3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+620)
"]   native: #12 pc 0000000000475b94  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art16ThreadPoolWorker3RunEv+88)
"]   native: #13 pc 0000000000475684  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art16ThreadPoolWorker8CallbackEPv+144)
"]   native: #14 pc 0000000000068150  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+36)
"]   native: #15 pc 000000000001f334  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
"]   (no managed stack frames)
"] 
"] "Signal Catcher" prio=5 tid=3 WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop
"]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x1bb000c0 self=0x72420c8400
"]   | sysTid=29595 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x723770b4f0
"]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
"]   | stack=0x7237611000-0x7237613000 stackSize=1005KB
"]   | held mutexes=
"]   kernel: __switch_to+0xd4/0xe0
"]   kernel: do_sigtimedwait+0x168/0x238
"]   kernel: SyS_rt_sigtimedwait+0xa0/0x118
"]   kernel: __sys_trace_return+0x0/0x4
"]   native: #00 pc 000000000006a988  /system/lib64/libc.so (__rt_sigtimedwait+8)
"]   native: #01 pc 0000000000029b88  /system/lib64/libc.so (sigwait+56)
"]   native: #02 pc 000000000044c470  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9SignalSet4WaitEv+40)
"]   native: #03 pc 000000000044bf94  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art13SignalCatcher13WaitForSignalEPNS_6ThreadERNS_9SignalSetE+256)
"]   native: #04 pc 000000000044aabc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art13SignalCatcher3RunEPv+276)
"]   native: #05 pc 0000000000068150  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+36)
"]   native: #06 pc 000000000001f334  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
"]   (no managed stack frames)
"] 
"] "JDWP" prio=5 tid=4 WaitingInMainDebuggerLoop
"]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x1bb00198 self=0x7237214400
"]   | sysTid=29596 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x72370894f0
"]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2 HZ=100
"]   | stack=0x7236f8f000-0x7236f91000 stackSize=1005KB
"]   | held mutexes=
"]   kernel: __switch_to+0x8c/0xe0
"]   kernel: poll_schedule_timeout+0x3c/0x64
"]   kernel: do_select+0x53c/0x5c4
"]   kernel: core_sys_select+0x1dc/0x38c
"]   kernel: SyS_pselect6+0x334/0x354
"]   kernel: __sys_trace_return+0x0/0x4
"]   native: #00 pc 000000000006a8e0  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pselect6+8)
"]   native: #01 pc 0000000000027cd8  /system/lib64/libc.so (select+148)
"]   native: #02 pc 0000000000514e38  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP12JdwpAdbState15ProcessIncomingEv+332)
"]   native: #03 pc 00000000002e9c44  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWP9JdwpState3RunEv+444)
"]   native: #04 pc 00000000002e9320  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art4JDWPL15StartJdwpThreadEPv+40)
"]   native: #05 pc 0000000000068150  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+36)
"]   native: #06 pc 000000000001f334  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
"]   (no managed stack frames)
"] 
"] "ReferenceQueueDaemon" prio=5 tid=5 Waiting
"]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x1bb00250 self=0x72420c9800
"]   | sysTid=29597 nice=4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7236f8c4f0
"]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
"]   | stack=0x7236e8a000-0x7236e8c000 stackSize=1037KB
"]   | held mutexes=
"]   kernel: __switch_to+0xd4/0xe0
"]   kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xd0/0x160
"]   kernel: futex_wait+0xe4/0x210
"]   kernel: do_futex+0x168/0xc48
"]   kernel: SyS_futex+0x11c/0x1b0
"]   kernel: __sys_trace_return+0x0/0x4
"]   native: #00 pc 000000000001dc6c  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
"]   native: #01 pc 00000000000e1c5c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable16WaitHoldingLocksEPNS_6ThreadE+152)
"]   native: #02 pc 00000000003928a0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Monitor4WaitEPNS_6ThreadElibNS_11ThreadStateE+628)
"]   native: #03 pc 0000000000394380  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Monitor4WaitEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_6mirror6ObjectElibNS_11ThreadStateE+252)
"]   native: #04 pc 000000000000070c  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (Java_java_lang_Object_wait__+124)
"]   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native method)
"]   - waiting on <0x0ea7af24> (a java.lang.Class<java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue>)
"]   at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:178)
"]   - locked <0x0ea7af24> (a java.lang.Class<java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue>)
"]   at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:103)
"]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
"] 
"] "FinalizerDaemon" prio=5 tid=6 Waiting
"]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x1bb007e0 self=0x72420ca200
"]   | sysTid=29598 nice=4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7236e874f0
"]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
"]   | stack=0x7236d85000-0x7236d87000 stackSize=1037KB
"]   | held mutexes=
"]   kernel: __switch_to+0xd4/0xe0
"]   kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xd0/0x160
"]   kernel: futex_wait+0xe4/0x210
"]   kernel: do_futex+0x168/0xc48
"]   kernel: SyS_futex+0x11c/0x1b0
"]   kernel: __sys_trace_return+0x0/0x4
"]   native: #00 pc 000000000001dc6c  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
"]   native: #01 pc 00000000000e1c5c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable16WaitHoldingLocksEPNS_6ThreadE+152)
"]   native: #02 pc 00000000003928a0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Monitor4WaitEPNS_6ThreadElibNS_11ThreadStateE+628)
"]   native: #03 pc 0000000000394380  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Monitor4WaitEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_6mirror6ObjectElibNS_11ThreadStateE+252)
"]   native: #04 pc 0000000000000adc  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (Java_java_lang_Object_wait__JI+140)
"]   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native method)
"]   - waiting on <0x0e9aba8d> (a java.lang.Object)
"]   at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:422)
"]   at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:188)
"]   - locked <0x0e9aba8d> (a java.lang.Object)
"]   at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:209)
"]   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:232)
"]   at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:103)
"]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
"] 
"] "FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" prio=5 tid=7 Waiting
"]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x1bb02580 self=0x722bcd2000
"]   | sysTid=29599 nice=4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7236d824f0
"]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2 HZ=100
"]   | stack=0x7236c80000-0x7236c82000 stackSize=1037KB
"]   | held mutexes=
"]   kernel: __switch_to+0xd4/0xe0
"]   kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xd0/0x160
"]   kernel: futex_wait+0xe4/0x210
"]   kernel: do_futex+0x168/0xc48
"]   kernel: SyS_futex+0x11c/0x1b0
"]   kernel: __sys_trace_return+0x0/0x4
"]   native: #00 pc 000000000001dc6c  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
"]   native: #01 pc 00000000000e1c5c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable16WaitHoldingLocksEPNS_6ThreadE+152)
"]   native: #02 pc 00000000003928a0  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Monitor4WaitEPNS_6ThreadElibNS_11ThreadStateE+628)
"]   native: #03 pc 0000000000394380  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Monitor4WaitEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_6mirror6ObjectElibNS_11ThreadStateE+252)
"]   native: #04 pc 000000000000070c  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (Java_java_lang_Object_wait__+124)
"]   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native method)
"]   - waiting on <0x02c69442> (a java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon)
"]   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.sleepUntilNeeded(Daemons.java:297)
"]   - locked <0x02c69442> (a java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon)
"]   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:277)
"]   at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:103)
"]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
"] 
"] "Binder:29589_1" prio=5 tid=9 Native
"]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x1bb02f38 self=0x722bcd5c00
"]   | sysTid=29601 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7236a7a4f0
"]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
"]   | stack=0x7236980000-0x7236982000 stackSize=1005KB
"]   | held mutexes=
"]   kernel: __switch_to+0xd4/0xe0
"]   kernel: binder_thread_read+0x414/0x14c0
"]   kernel: binder_ioctl+0x72c/0x9c0
"]   kernel: do_vfs_ioctl+0x514/0x79c
"]   kernel: SyS_ioctl+0x84/0x98
"]   kernel: __sys_trace_return+0x0/0x4
"]   native: #00 pc 000000000006a894  /system/lib64/libc.so (__ioctl+4)
"]   native: #01 pc 00000000000244c4  /system/lib64/libc.so (ioctl+132)
"]   native: #02 pc 0000000000061b48  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14talkWithDriverEb+256)
"]   native: #03 pc 0000000000061cb8  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState20getAndExecuteCommandEv+24)
"]   native: #04 pc 00000000000623e8  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14joinThreadPoolEb+72)
"]   native: #05 pc 0000000000082d60  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (???)
"]   native: #06 pc 0000000000011754  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+280)
"]   native: #07 pc 00000000000bc070  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+136)
"]   native: #08 pc 0000000000068150  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+36)
"]   native: #09 pc 000000000001f334  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
"]   (no managed stack frames)
"] 
"] "Binder:29589_2" prio=5 tid=10 Native
"]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x1bb03048 self=0x723722b800
"]   | sysTid=29602 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x723697d4f0
"]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=1 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
"]   | stack=0x7236883000-0x7236885000 stackSize=1005KB
"]   | held mutexes=
"]   kernel: __switch_to+0x8c/0xe0
"]   kernel: binder_thread_read+0x414/0x14c0
"]   kernel: binder_ioctl+0x72c/0x9c0
"]   kernel: do_vfs_ioctl+0x514/0x79c
"]   kernel: SyS_ioctl+0x84/0x98
"]   kernel: __sys_trace_return+0x0/0x4
"]   native: #00 pc 000000000006a894  /system/lib64/libc.so (__ioctl+4)
"]   native: #01 pc 00000000000244c4  /system/lib64/libc.so (ioctl+132)
"]   native: #02 pc 0000000000061b48  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14talkWithDriverEb+256)
"]   native: #03 pc 0000000000061cb8  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState20getAndExecuteCommandEv+24)
"]   native: #04 pc 00000000000623e8  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (_ZN7android14IPCThreadState14joinThreadPoolEb+72)
"]   native: #05 pc 0000000000082d60  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (???)
"]   native: #06 pc 0000000000011754  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+280)
"]   native: #07 pc 00000000000bc070  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+136)
"]   native: #08 pc 0000000000068150  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+36)
"]   native: #09 pc 000000000001f334  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
"]   (no managed stack frames)
"] 
"] "Profile Saver" prio=5 tid=11 Native
"]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x1bb03140 self=0x72420e6000
"]   | sysTid=29604 nice=9 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x723617e4f0
"]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=1 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
"]   | stack=0x7236084000-0x7236086000 stackSize=1005KB
"]   | held mutexes=
"]   kernel: __switch_to+0xd4/0xe0
"]   kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xd0/0x160
"]   kernel: futex_wait+0xe4/0x210
"]   kernel: do_futex+0x168/0xc48
"]   kernel: SyS_futex+0x11c/0x1b0
"]   kernel: __sys_trace_return+0x0/0x4
"]   native: #00 pc 000000000001dc70  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+32)
"]   native: #01 pc 00000000000e2084  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable9TimedWaitEPNS_6ThreadEli+172)
"]   native: #02 pc 000000000030984c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art12ProfileSaver3RunEv+536)
"]   native: #03 pc 000000000030b700  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art12ProfileSaver21RunProfileSaverThreadEPv+88)
"]   native: #04 pc 0000000000068150  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+36)
"]   native: #05 pc 000000000001f334  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
"]   (no managed stack frames)
"] 
"] "Thread-4" prio=5 tid=12 Native
"]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x1bb03450 self=0x722bcdf000
"]   | sysTid=29606 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x723600c4f0
"]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
"]   | stack=0x7235f0a000-0x7235f0c000 stackSize=1037KB
"]   | held mutexes=
"]   kernel: __switch_to+0xd4/0xe0
"]   kernel: __skb_recv_datagram+0x470/0x4a8
"]   kernel: skb_recv_datagram+0x3c/0x5c
"]   kernel: unix_accept+0x98/0x164
"]   kernel: SyS_accept4+0x12c/0x228
"]   kernel: __sys_trace_return+0x0/0x4
"]   native: #00 pc 000000000006a744  /system/lib64/libc.so (__accept4+4)
"]   native: #01 pc 00000000000011d0  /system/lib64/libnetd_client.so (???)
"]   native: #02 pc 0000000000029f20  /system/lib64/libjavacore.so (???)
"]   native: #03 pc 00000000002531d4  /system/framework/arm64/boot-core-libart.oat (Java_libcore_io_Linux_accept__Ljava_io_FileDescriptor_2Ljava_net_SocketAddress_2+180)
"]   at libcore.io.Linux.accept(Native method)
"]   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.accept(BlockGuardOs.java:64)
"]   at android.system.Os.accept(Os.java:43)
"]   at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.accept(LocalSocketImpl.java:337)
"]   at android.net.LocalServerSocket.accept(LocalServerSocket.java:90)
"]   at com.android.tools.ir.server.Server$SocketServerThread.run(Server.java:165)
"]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
"] 
"] "RenderThread" prio=5 tid=14 Native
"]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x13540c40 self=0x7237231c00
"]   | sysTid=29611 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7221d024f0
"]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=77 stm=17 core=2 HZ=100
"]   | stack=0x7221c08000-0x7221c0a000 stackSize=1005KB
"]   | held mutexes=
"]   kernel: __switch_to+0x8c/0xe0
"]   kernel: SyS_epoll_wait+0x3bc/0x4b4
"]   kernel: SyS_epoll_pwait+0x134/0x140
"]   kernel: __sys_trace_return+0x0/0x4
"]   native: #00 pc 000000000006a7a8  /system/lib64/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+8)
"]   native: #01 pc 000000000001fb28  /system/lib64/libc.so (epoll_pwait+48)
"]   native: #02 pc 0000000000015d54  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper9pollInnerEi+144)
"]   native: #03 pc 0000000000015c3c  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper8pollOnceEiPiS1_PPv+108)
"]   native: #04 pc 0000000000054620  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (_ZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread12RenderThread10threadLoopEv+884)
"]   native: #05 pc 0000000000011754  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+280)
"]   native: #06 pc 00000000000bc070  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+136)
"]   native: #07 pc 0000000000068150  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+36)
"]   native: #08 pc 000000000001f334  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
"]   (no managed stack frames)
"] 
"] "hwuiTask1" prio=5 tid=13 Native
"]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x13540cc8 self=0x722d9d9a00
"]   | sysTid=29620 nice=-2 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x721e7ff4f0
"]   | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=2 stm=1 core=0 HZ=100
"]   | stack=0x721e705000-0x721e707000 stackSize=1005KB
"]   | held mutexes=
"]   kernel: __switch_to+0xd4/0xe0
"]   kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xd0/0x160
"]   kernel: futex_wait+0xe4/0x210
"]   kernel: do_futex+0x168/0xc48
"]   kernel: SyS_futex+0x11c/0x1b0
"]   kernel: __sys_trace_return+0x0/0x4
"]   native: #00 pc 000000000001dc6c  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
"]   native: #01 pc 00000000000677cc  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_cond_wait+96)
"]   native: #02 pc 0000000000056b50  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (???)
"]   native: #03 pc 0000000000011754  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+280)
"]   native: #04 pc 00000000000bc070  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+136)
"] "queued-work-looper" prio=5 tid=17 Native
"]   native: #02 pc 0000000000015d54  /system/lib64/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper9pollInnerEi+144)
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 29600 (HeapTaskDaemon)
```

Comment: SIGABRT can occur when the OS determines the application is hanging. Are you doing anything intensive in the UI thread? Could you share more details about when the error occurs- does it happen when the app starts for example? Also please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36693887/what-is-fatal-signal-6-in-android-logcat

Comment: I took a look at the Stackoverflow question, but I think that I am following the guidelines. I dont think there is much work on the UI thread. It appears very randomly. But always on views where I have custom controls. Could that be a cause? The problem also is that this bug appears so irregular that sometimes it does not even crash once for one hour...

Comment: Maybe the following infos help: It happens only on my device. I tested is with an emulator and never had a crash there. Also it always crashes exactly after Android system triggers the garbage collection. @Noremac

Comment: @julien-100000 Have you figured out what it was? I'm getting this error for all Samsung phones in Firebase TestLabs.

Comment: @julien-100000 Actually appears to be all Firebase TestLab devices on API level 26. 24/26+ work fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what causes the problem in my case. Maybe it helps.

`Context`:
I used `Reflection` in my project. I had some private fields and wanted to fill them automatically via reflection.

To achieve this, I did the following:

```
Field field = MyClass.class.getDeclaredField("MyField");
field.setAccessible(true);
field.set(classInstance, "SomeValue");
field.setAccessible(false); // <- exactly this line was causing this error
```

After removing that line everything worked 100% fine and I never got the error again. I am not 100% sure why, but as far as I now understand, it is not necessary to reset the accessible flag to false again, because this is done automatically.

Comment: This looks very promising. I am too using reflection, but only setting accessible = true; will investigate tomorrow and report back. The thread reported in the crash matches the thread that last modified some field accessibility flags.

Comment: I had similar problem using getDeclaredField() and I just add a try{}catch(){} block, to prevent the app from crashing

Answer (score 0):

After a giant hint from @julien-10000; I finally found the issue.

Apparently, some versions of Android, specifically API level 26, implement something called Brooks pointers. These pointers are intended to speed up GC, and manifest as extra fields in your classes. The fields are called `shadow$_klass_` and `shadow$_monitor_`.

I had a somewhat naive implementation of a serialisation protocol which examined classes at runtime, and assigned some values to these fields by accident. After a while the GC would crash with the cryptic message such as the one OP posted.