# Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 13929 (.AppTest.Project1), pid 13929 (.AppTest.Project1)

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I've been pulling my hair out the last week as I've been getting this error and I've been unsuccessful in troubleshooting it after many, many hours.

I'm building a mobile application using C#, Visual Studio 2019, Xamarin.Forms and to test I've used both an Android emulator and my own Google Pixel 3a. A month ago this was working perfectly however all of a sudden I've been getting this error mentioned in the title, the log I've posted below.

I beg anyone to please help me out if they've got some experience dealing with this or have seen it before. I've deleted everything, reinstalled, used older versions, updated all packages etc... Still doesn't want to work for me.

I'm unsure whether or not it's within the code or a problem with Visual Studio/ my Android device. I believe it's the latter as there doesn't seem to be any problems when my colleagues test the code on their end, however they are using emulators/different devices.

```
08-06 16:21:37.857 F/libc    (13929): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 13929 (.AppTest.Project1), pid 13929 (.AppTest.Project1)
```

Full log can be found here: https://pastebin.com/sMwBh3E1

Any sort of help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is fatal signal 6 in android logcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36693887/what-is-fatal-signal-6-in-android-logcat)

Comment: do you get that in release mode with AOT only? i see in your logs that you are running aot

Comment: If you want, you could share your code where you might be facing the issue, and we could try to diagnose that

Answer (score 1):

> JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI IsInstanceOf called with pending exception java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB

Based on the constant cycling of Mono garbage collections that ends in a  `java.lang.StackOverflowError`, you have an endless loop or recursion happening within the Java ART runtime, with the top of the call stack starting at the MainActvity OnCreate method.

Since this is causing constant Mono GCing and then a Java StackOverflow, the code is effecting both runtimes (Mono and ART) and you should look at any calls that are going across the Java-Mono bridge.

You will need to work your way down that call stack to find the root issue, either single stepping though the MainActivity code or going down the call stack in the log to narrow down it down.