# Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) in AsyncTask Android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask

I am compressing Bitmap in asynctask and sending it to another activity through Bundle and I am getting this crash. I am calling Bitmap.recycle() in my code. Sometime it works properly, here is my Logcat output.

```
Called getHeight() on a recycle()'d bitmap! This is undefined behavior!
2020-01-14 16:25:56.863 21779-22017/ W/Bitmap: Called getWidth() on a recycle()'d bitmap! This is undefined behavior!
2020-01-14 16:25:56.863 21779-22017/ W/Bitmap: Called getWidth() on a recycle()'d bitmap! This is undefined behavior!
2020-01-14 16:25:56.863 21779-22017/ W/Bitmap: Called getHeight() on a recycle()'d bitmap! This is undefined behavior!
2020-01-14 16:25:56.863 21779-22017/ W/Bitmap: Called getWidth() on a recycle()'d bitmap! This is undefined behavior!
2020-01-14 16:25:56.863 21779-22017/ W/Bitmap: Called getHeight() on a recycle()'d bitmap! This is undefined behavior!
2020-01-14 16:25:56.863 21779-22017/ W/Bitmap: Called getWidth() on a recycle()'d bitmap! This is undefined behavior!
2020-01-14 16:25:56.863 21779-22017/ W/Bitmap: Called getHeight() on a recycle()'d bitmap! This is undefined behavior!
2020-01-14 16:25:56.863 21779-22017/ W/Bitmap: Called getConfig() on a recycle()'d bitmap! This is undefined behavior!
2020-01-14 16:25:56.863 21779-22017/ W/Bitmap: Called getConfig() on a recycle()'d bitmap! This is undefined behavior!
2020-01-14 16:25:56.863 21779-22017/ W/Bitmap: Called hasAlpha() on a recycle()'d bitmap! This is undefined behavior!
2020-01-14 16:25:56.864 21779-22017/ A/Bitmap: Error, cannot access an invalid/free'd bitmap here!
2020-01-14 16:25:56.864 21779-22017/ A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 22017 (AsyncTask #5), pid 21779
```

Here is the code to Compress Image

```
private static void compressImage(final Bitmap bitmap, final Callback<Bitmap> gbCallback) {

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {

            Bitmap image = getScaledImageCopy(bitmap);
            if (image != null) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, byteArrayOutputStream);

                byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
                image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
                return image;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            gbCallback.call(bitmap);
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);

 private static Bitmap getScaledImageCopyForUGC(Bitmap image) {
    try {
        int height = image.getHeight();
        int width = image.getWidth();
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, 400, (400 * height) / width, true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (image != null) {
            return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, 300, 300, true);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your code which you used to compress the bitmap

Comment: code added @TusharMonirul

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is fatal signal 6 in android logcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36693887/what-is-fatal-signal-6-in-android-logcat)

Answer (score 0):

Its seems like the bitmap is already recycled. You cant use a recycled bitmap. You need to make sure that the bitmap is not recycled which is passed in `compressImage`. For now you can check if the bitmap is recycled or not to avoid error.

```
if(!bitmap.isRecycled()){
    //bitmap is not recycled
}else {
    //bitmap is recycled, use a default placeholder
}
```