# A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 only on android N

Tags: android

I get the error A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in logcat only on android N when i open application settings and my application goes to the background. It happens more when my application is in the background .

This does not happen only while debugging and i use android studio . With turning on ANR on developer options , i dont get ANR.  It happens only on android N OS. It also happens when my app is in the background , and i open  applications settings on the phone.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android app crashes with SIGABRT Signal 6 only while Eclipse debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21595778/android-app-crashes-with-sigabrt-signal-6-only-while-eclipse-debugging)

Comment: This does not happen only while debugging and i use android studio . It happens only on android N OS.

Comment: Did you try searching the other log entries around it? might give you more details about the specific reason which caused the abort signal (that's what happened with my app).