# A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x0000315f (code=-6), thread 12639

Tags: android, multithreading, sigabrt

I have 5 tabs and `ViewPager` on `Home`. Every tab is working fine on all devices except a single one, and only on Samsung Galaxy S4. I can't figure out the problem. I am doing everything in `AsyncTask` to prevent this, but with no luck.

I have read about it, but nothing suits my need. There are no `Bitmaps`, or other heavy operations, this is simple static data which is causing this problem (I'm not sure if it's really)

I read that Android intentionally kills the process [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21595778/android-app-crashes-with-sigabrt-signal-6-only-while-eclipse-debugging), if this is the case, how do I prevent this?

Any help is highly appreciated.

For reference, here is my `Fragment` where this problem is occurring.

```
public class Book extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    ListView lstJildOne, lstJildTwo, lstJildThree;
    StyledTextView txtJildOne, txtJildTwo, txtJildThree, txtLoading;
    LinearLayout layout;

    final String VOLUME_ONE = "جلد اول", VOLUME_TWO = "جلد دوم", VOLUME_THREE = "جلد سوم";

    public void setTxtJildTwo(StyledTextView txtJildTwo) {
        this.txtJildTwo = txtJildTwo;
    }
    public StyledTextView getTxtJildTwo() {
        return txtJildTwo;
    }



    public void setTxtJildThree(StyledTextView txtJildThree) {
        this.txtJildThree = txtJildThree;
    }
    public StyledTextView getTxtJildThree() {
        return txtJildThree;
    }





    public void setLstJildTwo(ListView lstJildTwo) {
        this.lstJildTwo = lstJildTwo;
    }
    public ListView getLstJildTwo() {
        return lstJildTwo;
    }




    public void setLstJildThree(ListView lstJildThree) {
        this.lstJildThree = lstJildThree;
    }
    public ListView getLstJildThree() {
        return lstJildThree;
    }




    public Book() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_book, container, false);

        layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.main);

        lstJildOne = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lstJildOne);
        txtJildOne = (StyledTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtJildOne);
        txtJildOne.setOnClickListener(this);

        txtLoading = (StyledTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtLoading);

        lstJildOne.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CompleteBook.class);
                intent.putExtra("section", position + 1);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        new AddChildren().execute();
        new PopulateList().execute();

        return view;
    }

    public void showHideLists(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.txtJildOne:
                if(lstJildOne.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    lstJildOne.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    ((StyledTextView) view).setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_no_arrow),
                            null, null, null);

                } else {
                    lstJildOne.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ((StyledTextView) view).setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_arrow_down),
                            null, null, null);
                }

                if(lstJildTwo != null)
                    lstJildTwo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if(lstJildThree != null)
                    lstJildThree.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                txtJildTwo.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_no_arrow),
                        null, null, null);
                txtJildThree.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_no_arrow),
                        null, null, null);

                break;
            case 1:
                if(lstJildTwo.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    lstJildTwo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    ((StyledTextView) view).setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_no_arrow),
                            null, null, null);
                } else {
//                    if(lstJildTwo.getAdapter() == null) {
//                        lstJildTwo.setAdapter(new     BookContents(getContentsList(), getActivity()));
//                    }

                    lstJildTwo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ((StyledTextView) view).setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_arrow_down),
                            null, null, null);
                }

                if(lstJildOne != null)
                    lstJildOne.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                if(lstJildThree != null)
                    lstJildThree.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                txtJildOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_no_arrow),
                        null, null, null);
                txtJildThree.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_no_arrow),
                        null, null, null);

                break;
            case 2:
                if(lstJildThree.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    lstJildThree.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    ((StyledTextView) view).setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_no_arrow),
                            null, null, null);
                } else {
//                    if(lstJildThree.getAdapter() == null) {
//                        lstJildThree.setAdapter(new     BookContents(getContentsList(), getActivity()));
//                    }

                    lstJildThree.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ((StyledTextView) view).setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_arrow_down),
                            null, null, null);
              }
                if(lstJildOne != null)
                    lstJildOne.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                if(lstJildTwo != null)
                    lstJildTwo.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                txtJildOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_no_arrow),
                        null, null, null);
                txtJildTwo.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_no_arrow),
                        null, null, null);

                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        showHideLists(v);
    }


    private class PopulateList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, BookContents> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            txtJildOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_no_arrow),
                    null, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "View Loading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected BookContents doInBackground(Void... params) {
            List<Contents> contentsList = new ArrayList<>();
            Contents contents = new Contents();
            contents.setHeading(MakeNodes.SECTION_ONE_HEADING);
            contents.setDescription(MakeNodes.getSubSectionOneList());
            contentsList.add(contents);

            contents = new Contents();
            contents.setHeading(MakeNodes.SECTION_TWO_HEADING);
            contents.setDescription(MakeNodes.getSubSectionTwoList());
            contentsList.add(contents);

            contents = new Contents();
            contents.setHeading(MakeNodes.SECTION_THREE_HEADING);
            contents.setDescription(MakeNodes.getSubSectionThreeList());
            contentsList.add(contents);

            contents = new Contents();
            contents.setHeading(MakeNodes.SECTION_FOUR_HEADING);
            contents.setDescription(MakeNodes.getSubSectionFourList());
            contentsList.add(contents);

            contents = new Contents();
            contents.setHeading(MakeNodes.SECTION_FIVE_HEADING);
            contents.setDescription(MakeNodes.getSubSectionFiveList());
            contentsList.add(contents);

            contents = new Contents();
            contents.setHeading(MakeNodes.SECTION_SIX_HEADING);
            contents.setDescription(MakeNodes.getSubSectionSixList());
            contentsList.add(contents);

            return new BookContents(contentsList, getActivity());
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(BookContents bookContents) {
            super.onPostExecute(bookContents);
            lstJildOne.setAdapter(bookContents);
            txtJildOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_arrow_down),
                    null, null, null);
            txtLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "View Loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    private class AddChildren extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "View being added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            setTxtJildTwo(getTextView(VOLUME_TWO, 1));
            setTxtJildThree(getTextView(VOLUME_THREE, 2));

            setLstJildTwo(getListView());
            setLstJildThree(getListView());

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            layout.addView(getTxtJildTwo());
            layout.addView(getLstJildTwo());

            layout.addView(getTxtJildThree());
            layout.addView(getLstJildThree());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "View Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }



    private StyledTextView getTextView(String text, int id) {
        StyledTextView textView = new StyledTextView(getActivity());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
        textView.setLayoutParams(params);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        textView.setPadding(6, 6, 6, 6);
        textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_no_arrow),
                null, null, null);
        textView.setText(text);
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);
        textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorPrimary));
        textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_gray);
        textView.setId(id);
        textView.setOnClickListener(this);
        return textView;
    }

    private ListView getListView() {
        ListView listView = new ListView(getActivity());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        return  listView;
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the complete stack trace.

```
03-07 12:13:55.884 12264-12264/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file.

03-07 12:13:55.884 12264-12264/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority [1], There is no sepolicy version file.

03-07 12:13:55.884 12264-12264/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority , loading version is VE=SEPF_SGH-M919_4.4.2_0004


03-07 12:13:55.884 12264-12264/? I/SELinux: selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /seapp_contexts
03-07 12:13:55.894 12264-12264/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
03-07 12:13:55.995 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat W/ApplicationPackageManager: getCSCPackageItemText()
03-07 12:13:56.005 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts, referenced from method     android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts
03-07 12:13:56.005 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 21539: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts (Ljava/util/List;Landroid/view/Menu;I)V
03-07 12:13:56.005 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
03-07 12:13:56.005 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
03-07 12:13:56.005 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
03-07 12:13:56.005 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 21541: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
03-07 12:13:56.005 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
03-07 12:13:56.005 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
03-07 12:13:56.005 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 21545: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
03-07 12:13:56.005 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
03-07 12:13:56.015 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
03-07 12:13:56.015 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 511: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
03-07 12:13:56.015 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-07 12:13:56.015 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
03-07 12:13:56.015 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 533: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
03-07 12:13:56.015 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0008
03-07 12:13:56.045 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.<init>, referenced from method com.dawateislami.bahareshariat.customizations.StyledTextView.<init>
03-07 12:13:56.045 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve direct method 22412: Landroid/widget/TextView;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;II)V
03-07 12:13:56.045 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0000
03-07 12:13:56.295 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:381>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL3869936)
                                                                        OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.11.SPL
                                                                        Build Date: 01/17/14 Fri
                                                                        Local Branch: 
                                                                        Remote Branch: 
                                                                        Local Patches: 
                                                                        Reconstruct Branch: 
03-07 12:13:56.345 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
03-07 12:13:57.296 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat W/ApplicationPackageManager: getCSCPackageItemText()
03-07 12:13:57.316 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList
03-07 12:13:57.316 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 311: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
03-07 12:13:57.316 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
03-07 12:13:57.626 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
03-07 12:13:57.626 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 474: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
03-07 12:13:57.626 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-07 12:13:57.626 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
03-07 12:13:57.626 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 476: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
03-07 12:13:57.626 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-07 12:13:57.636 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
03-07 12:13:57.636 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 154 (Landroid/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable;) in Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageHelper;
03-07 12:13:57.636 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x000c
03-07 12:13:58.147 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
03-07 12:13:58.407 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-07 12:13:58.417 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
03-07 12:13:58.427 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/AbsListView: onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 8
03-07 12:13:58.427 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-07 12:13:58.427 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-07 12:13:58.577 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-07 12:13:58.587 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/ProgressBar: updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
03-07 12:13:58.587 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/ProgressBar: updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
03-07 12:13:58.587 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/ProgressBar: updateDrawableBounds: right = 144
03-07 12:13:58.587 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/ProgressBar: updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 144
03-07 12:13:58.627 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-07 12:13:58.627 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-07 12:13:58.657 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-07 12:13:58.937 12264-12403/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
03-07 12:13:58.947 12264-12403/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
03-07 12:13:58.947 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-07 12:13:58.947 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-07 12:13:58.957 12264-12420/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat I/SQLiteAssetHelper: successfully opened database Bahar_e_Shariat.db
03-07 12:13:59.007 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-07 12:13:59.007 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-07 12:13:59.017 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-07 12:14:02.251 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-07 12:14:02.251 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-07 12:14:02.251 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-07 12:14:02.291 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/AbsListView: onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
03-07 12:14:02.291 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-07 12:14:04.553 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-07 12:14:08.527 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat     I/Choreographer: Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-07 12:14:12.401 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-07 12:14:12.401 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-07 12:14:12.401 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-07 12:14:12.401 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-07 12:14:12.401 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat W/ApplicationPackageManager: getCSCPackageItemText()
03-07 12:14:12.641 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat V/WebViewChromium: Binding Chromium to the background looper Looper (main, tid 1) {42ab9888}
03-07 12:14:12.641 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(112)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
03-07 12:14:12.651 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat I/BrowserProcessMain: Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
03-07 12:14:12.651 12264-12662/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat W/chromium: [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(888)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
03-07 12:14:12.661 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat W/ApplicationPackageManager: getCSCPackageItemText()
03-07 12:14:13.191 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
03-07 12:14:13.201 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat I/SQLiteAssetHelper: successfully opened database Bahar_e_Shariat.db
03-07 12:14:13.211 12264-12683/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat I/SQLiteAssetHelper: successfully opened database Bahar_e_Shariat.db
03-07 12:14:13.221 12264-12275/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat I/dalvikvm: Total arena pages for JIT: 11
03-07 12:14:13.221 12264-12275/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat I/dalvikvm: Total arena pages for JIT: 12
03-07 12:14:13.221 12264-12275/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat I/dalvikvm: Total arena pages for JIT: 13
03-07 12:14:13.221 12264-12275/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat I/dalvikvm: Total arena pages for JIT: 14
03-07 12:14:13.231 12264-12275/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat I/dalvikvm: Total arena pages for JIT: 15
03-07 12:14:13.251 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/AbsListView: onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
03-07 12:14:13.251 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-07 12:14:13.261 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/AbsListView: onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
03-07 12:14:13.261 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-07 12:14:13.271 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called 
03-07 12:14:14.833 12264-12264/com.dawateislami.bahareshariat A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00002fe8 (code=-6), thread 12264 (i.bahareshariat)
```

Comment: Post the full stack trace, not just one line.  There's more info there.  From what little I can tell, it looks like an illegal memory address was accessed, but to tell any more you'd need the rest of the dump

Comment: It's been added.

Comment: And the stuff below it. It won't end with that, three will either be a c attack gave or a java one below it

Comment: It's the complete stack trace, nothing above or below it.

Comment: Remove your filter or something. There is always more to it

Comment: I haven't applied any filter. Are they enabled by default? If yes, how can I remove them?

Comment: Depends how you're accessing logcat. If using android studio, yes. Id's one of the drop downs above the messages. If using command line, then no

Comment: I believe it's a complete stack trace. No addition on changing anything from drop down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a custom `TextView` with font. The size of that font was more than 10 MB. That was actually the culprit. On removing the font, it's working fine.